# How to access data from redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

So I would like to fetch some data with an API, then store it into my Redux Store to use it everywhere.

The fetch is working great and my console shows me that the action and the reducer are also working.

[image: Console Capture]

But in my "List" Component, `this.props` is `undefined` (cf. console capture) in my render method and my constructor.

To make it simple, I made a codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/embed/reduxcrypto-k16tz

I don't know what to do.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This thing in your reducer erases response content:

```js
cryptoDataCopy = {
  currency: action.currency // there is no currency field in your action
  // probably you want to use action.payload and save it to crypto field
  // since List tries to use crypto field
  // crypto: action.payload
};
```

Also, you're not using action payload in your reducer, but just copying previous state. There should be something to put payload into state.crypto:

```js
...
var cryptoDataCopy = { ...cryptoData, crypto: '123' };
  // cryptoDataCopy.currency = {
  //   currency: action.currency
  // }

  return {
    ...cryptoData,
    currency: action.currency,  // actually, there is no such field in your action
    crypto: action.payload
  };
```

And your request doesn't return anything. You can add catch to see logs about failed request:

```js
.then(response => {
  ...
}).catch(
  () => {
    console.log('no response')
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I update the code in the Codesandbox, that's not the problem

Comment: here is a link for you https://codesandbox.io/s/reduxcrypto-91rfv?fontsize=14

Comment: Thanks for your help and the link, but I think this is the same. My this.props is still undefined when i'm console logging it in List component

Comment: When I edit the `mapStateToProps`
From : `const mapStateToProps = state => ({ crypto: state.crypto });`
To : `const mapStateToProps = state => ({ crypto: state});`

Then the console log of `this.props` is changing 
From : ` {crypto: Undefined}`
To : `{crypto: array(0)}` 

The problem is maybe from this, i need the data now

Comment: Why the error is triggered in my fetch ? my console shows me the payload full of data

Comment: @Stave You cannot make cross site xml http request, the browser won't let you. It's called CORS and you can develop with [cors plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf) to allow CORS.

Comment: Please, check my link - it works and you will see the result of your failed request in crypto field. Your problem is that your action dispatches object with `payload` field which is `response.data`, then in your reducer you're spreading it into an array, so your state is an array, not an object, but you're trying to extract `crypto` field from this state. There is no such field, why are you trying to read it?